# can't select items with Rails and Javascript with Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have a select2 selection on `#user_languages`

`@user` has an array of languages

I am trying to select those langauges with

```
$("#user_languages").select2( "val","<%=j @user.languages %>");
```

but I am getting

```
undefined method `gsub' for ["English", "Spanish", "French"]:Array
```

Comment: `select2( "val","<%= @user.languages %>")`

Comment: result script is   `$("#user_languages").select2( "val", "[&quot;English&quot;,&quot;Spanish&quot;,&quot;French&quot;]" );`

Comment: yes for  `select2( "val","<%=raw @user.languages %>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `to_json` instead of `j` and double qoute(`"`) :

```
$("#user_languages").select2( "val",<%=h @user.languages.to_json %>);
```

Comment: that gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

Comment: If I add double quotes the resulting script is   `$("#user_languages").select2( "val", "[&quot;English&quot;,&quot;Spanish&quot;,&quot;French&quot;]" );`

Comment: add `.html_safe` or `h` in the beginning. Updated the answer

Comment: although there is some minor mistake please use h instead of html_safe

Comment: @NickGinanto look at my comments `select2( "val","<%=raw @user.languages %>")`